# How to Insert Cells (not Entire Row/Column) in Excel using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

As the title suggested, I'm not sure how to do the equivalent of selecting only a portion of a row and insert cells (shift rows down) using Powershell. It seems like all tutorials online are about inserting the entire row or entire column which is not what I want to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $true

$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open "C:\path\to\your.xlsx"
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)

$ws.Range("C5:E9").Insert(-4121)
```

Comment: @Ansgar Would you happen to know how to avoid shifting all your cell formatting and excel functions when doing this? Example..I have a chart referencing 'A2:B40' on another sheet, if i do '$ws.Range("A2:B40").Insert(-4121)' my chart references change to 'A41:B81' also it takes my header formatting, and extends it to the entire length of the insert. Is there a way to avoid this from happening? I can't seem to find help anywhere..

Comment: @BigRabbit It's the default behavior. If you want the inserted range formatted differently you need to change the formatting after the insert.